# Facebook returning HTTP status code 502 while making a GET Request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, http-status-codes

I am trying a GET request from Facebook for a batch of ids using my app access token separated by a comma.

Please find below the call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=1374186930,100005305471358,1516423103,100003031846875,100002939786624,100004705179654,522691095,100002893804783,100005269178084,1417831236,100004652521769,100003511989378,100002394692546,1646211152,1092931510,100000152985362,100004151552444,100004122698187,100001574061632,100005007584068&access_token=<my_app_access_token>&format=json
```

Facebook returns an error intermittently for some of these requests with an HTTP status code of 502.

I've tried fetching for these ids using the graph API explorer as well as the app access token later. They have been fetched properly. I have performed some research, but all issues of Facebook were related to open graph and 502 is "Bad Gateway Error". Since mine is not a web app, I cannot even refresh a browser to make the call again. This is a normal call made to Facebook API.

The error returned by Facebook is html which contains the following message:
"Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can."

Since they have given this response, I want to know if someone is facing this issue as well and if somebody could tell me, when this will be resolved.

This is affecting the other calls as well and there is a delay in the fetching.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you get a 502 intermittently, then run a check on the response and if its invalid run it (or a modified) version again. Good coding practices have failure-methods

Comment: @TommyCrush I'd like to know if it is normal for Facebook to return such errors in intervals of 3 to 4 hours in a day. I've noticed this for the past one week and have constantly monitored the occurrence. Since they have stated that they will fix this issue, is there a timeline within which they do complete it?

Comment: There is no set timeline, depends entirely on the scope and severity of the bug.

Answer (score -2):

The Error 502 means that the message is too large. I do not know exactly the maximum size. Curiosity. What language are you using??

Good Bye

Comment: I am using Java and making requests to Facebook via a jar provided by restfb.com. This error has been observed while fetching for a batch of userids or comments of a post.